# How to create Web History for my Browser

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qwebkit, qt4.8, qwebpage

I'm new to Qt. I am Trying to create a Sample Browser Application. I had created the Browser application. Now i need to create the Web history for my application. I don't know how to do it.  can anyone please help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with/trying to do? QWebPages all have a QWebHistory member for that, what are you trying to achieve that you can't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`QWebHistory * QWebView::history ()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwebview.html#history)

The Arora Browser is based in the QWebView... as mentioned [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/demos-browser.html).

> This browser is the foundation for the Arora Browser, a simple
>   cross-platform Web browser.

I would look at how they implemented their [history](https://github.com/Arora/arora/tree/master/src/history).

In the end, though I would look through accessing the elements of [`QWebHistory`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwebhistory.html) and figure out how you want to display them and maybe use the [`QWebHistoryInterface`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwebhistoryinterface.html).